# Display multiple validation messages to the user

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2007

In MS-Access, how can I store the rows retrieved from my SELECT statement in an array, and show many rows in one messagebox:

```
Dim rSEL, rSUM, rDes As DAO.Recordset
Dim vItem_id, vQnty, vSum As Integer
Dim vDes As String
If Not IsNull(itemId) And Not IsNull(qnty_in) Then
    If qnty_in <= 0 Or qnty_in > balance Or IsNull(balance) Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
    Set rSEL = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT item_id,item_qnty 
               FROM basketQnty_tbl WHERE basket_id=" & basketId)
    'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
    If Not (rSEL.EOF And rSEL.BOF) Then
    rSEL.MoveFirst
    Do Until rSEL.EOF
        'Save itemId into a variable
        vItem_id = rSEL!item_id
        vQnty = (rSEL!item_qnty) * qnty_in
        Set rSUM = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT sum(qnty_in*qnty_type) 
                   as QN FROM sales_tbl WHERE itemid=" & vItem_id)
        Set rDes = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT itemDesc 
                   FROM items_main WHERE itemId=" & vItem_id)
        vSum = rSUM!QN
        vDes = rDes!itemDesc
        'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
        If vQnty > vSum Then
            MsgBox "you have only (" & vSum & " ) of Item (" & vDes & " ) in the stock"
            Cancel = True
        End If
    rSEL.MoveNext
    Loop
    End If
   rSEL.Close
End If
```

Comment: Why do you want to store returned records in an array?

Comment: I want to show messagebox that said your dont have enaugh qnty of the listed items

Comment: You don't need an array to take out data from a recordset and show in a message box.

Comment: Mr. @MarkBertenshaw I know
I could show masgebox for every record ... when I click OK it shows ... another mesagebox
but I want to show one messagebox which show all selected records in one messagebox

Comment: I guessed that after reading the question a while. In general, never put a message box in a loop, unless you are going to exit the loop right-away. Anyhow, I've answered the question below.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway have you known [`GetRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee275120%28v=BTS.10%29.aspx) method in both DAO and ADO? You may use it in your case.

```
yourarray = recordset.GetRows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a Message Box for this, since you could potentially have hundreds of rows, and they wouldn't all fit. Instead, I would create a custom form with a ListBox, and whenever you get the error, do the following:

```
If vQnty > vSum Then
    <ErrorForm>.<ListBox>.AddItem("You have only (" & vSum & " ) of Item (" & vDes & " ) in the stock")
    Cancel = True
End If
```

If at the end of the loop, Cancel = True, display ErrorForm.

Another thing - you may be able to create a query which does all this in one go. You need to join the three tables, and add the vQnty > vSum condition. This would be pretty neat, because you could use the query as the source of the ListBox - no code required.

Comment: I want to show messagebox which say user there is no enaugh qnty of the selected item , and show this items in one messagebox

Comment: @user1364008 In the code sample you have given, there is no concept of "selected item". You have a basket id, and the basket contains items. Can you please change your question to reflect what you want to do? It is way too ambiguous at the moment.

Comment: I want to include the selected items in an array then I want to desplay it in an messagebox
<pre><code>        If vQnty > vSum Then
        ArrX=array(vsum,vdes)
    'MsgBox "you have only (" & vSum & " ) of Item (" & vDes & " ) in the stock"
            Cancel = True
        End If
    rSEL.MoveNext
    Loop
msgbox ArrX
</code>

Comment: What if you have 100 items that have failed this validation? You wouldn't be able to see them all, and the Message Box would fill up the entire screen!